# Layout breaks while page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using the a slider to display some WordPress posts. When I open the page, it hangs for some seconds (time varies) during that time, the layout breaks (for example all posts in slider become visible instead of first post), but as soon the page loads every thing gets back to normal.

I think this is because the jQuery code loads late. Is there anything I can do about that?

I'm currenly using this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#foo1").carouFredSel();
});
```

Also how can I check with the **Firebug** that what is causing this? (which resource is taking time to load), because it happens so quickly that I don't get time to see on Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide it and make its display:none . till it loads then show it

```
<script>    
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#foo1").carouFredSel();
jQuery("#foo1").show();
});
</script>
<div id="foo1" style="display:none"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebug has a net panel that will allow you to view requests/responses made and received by the browser.

[image]

I'm assuming that it is most likely not jQuery.  After you visit the site a few times it should be in your cache.